# Connect to Firebird database as read-only

Tags: python, firebird, fdb

I want to connect to a Firebird database read-only (because the location where the `.fdb` is read-only for my application.

I connect like this:

```
conn = fdb.connect(dsn="/path/to.fdb", user='****', password='****', charset='iso8859_1')
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -551\n- no permission for read-write access to database /path/to.fdb', -551, 335544352

I am using FDB v2.0. I couldn't find anything in the online documentation about a read-only connection.

Comment: Are you connecting through Firebird server (and if not, why not), and would that have read/write access? Do you need the database to be read-only for everyone or just this application?

Comment: Not through a server (because it was a hassle to set up and this worked before). The database needs to be read-only just for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want is not possible. Firebird doesn't have a concept of read-only connections. Every connection needs to be able to write information in the database for administration of transactions (this even applies for read-only transactions).

The only exception is for databases that have been marked as a [read-only database using gfix](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gfix/firebird-gfix.html#gfix-dbmode). In that case, transactions piggyback on the last committed transaction id. However, marking a database read-only will make it read-only for all connections.

If your application needs read-only access, while other applications need write access to the same database, the only solution is to use Firebird server*, and use users (and roles) to assign sufficient rights to be able to read but not write to the database.

---

<sup>*: Firebird Embedded might be sufficient, but as the user then needs read/write access to the database, it would be simpler to circumvent this form of access control for malicious actors.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a good idea to create a user for the DB with a specific role, and use this role during further connections. Something like this:

```
$ isql firstdb.fdb -user SYSDBA -password masterkey
Database:  firstdb.fdb, User: SYSDBA
SQL> CREATE ROLE firstdbadmin;
SQL> GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON sales_catalog
CON> TO ROLE firstdbadmin;
SQL> GRANT firstdbadmin TO TestAdmin;
SQL> quit;
```

Have you tried use 'role' argument, while creating connection?
You may look [here](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/reference.html#fdb.connect),[here](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/html/paper-fb-macosx-getstart.html) and [here](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/python-db-api-compliance.html)